# react-native code push getting error in ios ,using pod

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-code-push

I am using code push in react native app but getting  error at compile time ,

pod version in project

```
# React Native requirements
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
   'Core',
   'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
   'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
   'RCTText',
   'RCTNetwork',
   'RCTWebSocket', # Needed for debugging
   'RCTAnimation', # Needed for FlatList and animations running on native UI thread
   # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
]
# Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

and **package.json**

```
"react-native-code-push": "^5.7.0",
 "react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.8",
```

**error** I am getting

```
 [![Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_JSObjectGetPrototype", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSObjectSetPrototype", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSPropertyNameAccumulatorAddName", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getPropertyNames(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSPropertyNameAccumulator*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSObjectCopyPropertyNames", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSContextGetGlobalObject", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::global() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSValueMakeString", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSValueIsNumber", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSClassCreate", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::$_0::operator()() const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::$_1::operator()() const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSObjectGetPropertyAtIndex", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getValueAtIndex(facebook::jsi::Array const&, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSObjectMakeArray", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createArray(unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSEvaluateScript", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSValueIsUndefined", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSPropertyNameArrayGetCount", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSPropertyNameArrayGetNameAtIndex", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSPropertyNameArrayRelease", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      "_JSValueMakeUndefined", referenced from:
          facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me;

```
cd ios
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
pod install --repo-update
```

After worked this lines you can try again run you project.

Also another solution as down below;

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install && yarn start --reset-cache
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, There seems to be grammatical error in sentence formation which might make it hard for people to comprehend, Can you please fix it?

Comment: Yeah I try to fix that :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the version of `SSZipArchive` from `2.1.x` to `2.2.x` on `CodePush.podspec` worked for me.

And to keep track of this change on my project I used [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package):

1. Open `node_modules/react-native-code-push/CodePush.podspec` and change the version of `SSZipArchive` from `~> 2.1` to `~> 2.2`:

```rb
s.dependency 'SSZipArchive', '~> 2.2' # Like this
```

2. Generate a patch:

```sh
$ yarn patch-package react-native-code-push
```

The patch file should look like this:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-code-push/CodePush.podspec b/node_modules/react-native-code-push/CodePush.podspec
index dca6e84..0b8928d 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-code-push/CodePush.podspec
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-code-push/CodePush.podspec
@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@ Pod::Spec.new do |s|
   # we explicitly let CocoaPods pull in the versions below so all dependencies are resolved and 
   # linked properly at a parent workspace level.
   s.dependency 'React'
-  s.dependency 'SSZipArchive', '~> 2.1'
+  s.dependency 'SSZipArchive', '~> 2.2'
   s.dependency 'JWT', '~> 3.0.0-beta.7'
   s.dependency 'Base64', '~> 1.1'
 end
```

3. Commit the patch:

```sh
$ git add patches/react-native-code-push+5.7.0.patch
$ git commit -m "patch(react-native-code-push): bump SSZipArchive to 2.2.x"
```

That's it.

**Note**: I'm using React Native `0.61.2` and code push `5.7.0`.